# Fazer um UPDATE condicional no ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma query que recebe os dados de um .csv e insere os dados na tabela.

Se a `position` for a mesma ele atualiza os campos. Preciso que além de verificar a `position` a query verifique se `status` é diferente de 1 (`status <> 1`) para poder atualizar.

Esse `status` não é passado pelo .csv fica apenas registrado no banco e não posso atualizar os registros que estão com `status = 1`.

Como fazer isso?

```
$import=
       "INSERT INTO registros (NAME, position, price)
        VALUES
        (
         '$data[1]',
         '$data[2]',
         '$data[3]'
        ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE position = position,
        NAME = '$data[1]',
        position = '$data[2]',
        price = '$data[3]',
        qty_try = 0";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a função [IF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

```
INSERT INTO registros (NAME, position, price)
    VALUES
    (
     '$data[1]',
     '$data[2]',
     '$data[3]'
    ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            /* SE  status atual for diferente de 1
               quando tivermos um position que 
               já existe     ,                           SE TRUE, SE FALSE */
    NAME     = IF(status <> 1,                        '$data[1]',     NAME),
    price    = IF(status <> 1,                        '$data[3]',    price),
    qty_try  = IF(status <> 1,                                 0,  qty_try);
```

Obs.: Não precisa verificar se campo `position` é igual ao que está sendo inserido se ele tiver um `CONSTRAINT UNIQUE` como você comentou na resposta do @Bacco, já que o `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` vai ser executado só quando tiver uma linha do `INSERT` com um `position` que já exista.

Referência:
http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2010/1/18/conditional-duplicate-key-updates-with-mysql

Comment: O valor de `status` é o do registro onde a `DUPLICATE KEY` foi encontrada.

Comment: Essa query funcionou, muito obrigado Thomas. o valor status é um campo que é alterado por outra query chamada através de um api quando passo uma url com name && price, então nessa query ele muda o status para 1. No caso da minha pergunta é uma query com atualizações do banco feita através de um importação. Não pude tentar a procedure pq só tenho acsso ao banco do trabalho, mas obrigado pela ajuda Bacco

Comment: @RafaelRibeiro Se vc testou e resolveu, creio que seja uma boa saída. Não dá pra especificar uma condição no UPDATE em si, mas como argumento para IF inline para manter o parâmetro igual ou não, conforme o `status`, é uma saída interessante (e tem meu +1).

Comment: @Bacco Só não precisaria se `position` fosse a `DUPLICATE KEY` em questão. Seria bom confirmar com o dono da pergunta antes de mudar.

Comment: @Bacco Bom, nesse caso então dá pra dizer que ON DUPLICATE KEY vai executar para os valores de `position` que foram violados, já que no INSERT ele não especifica a PRIMARY KEY. Então sim, dá até pra editar da resposta. Bem lembrado

Comment: @Bacco Ah, até que são didáticos :)

Answer (score 2):

Como o ON DUPLICATE KEY não permite situações condicionais **, talvez a melhor solução seja  uma *stored procedure*:

<sub>** mas veja um contorno para este limite na resposta do @Thomas, que transfere a condição para dentro dos parâmetros, que dá o mesmo efeito.</sub>

Com *stored procedure*, no PHP você faz isso:

```
$import = "CALL updateCustomizado( '$data[1]', '$data[2]', '$data[3]' );";
```

E no MySQL você cria a procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `updateCustomizado`(xname VARCHAR(20), xposition INT, xprice DECIMAL)
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM registros WHERE `position` = xposition) THEN
      UPDATE registros
      SET name=xname, price=xprice
      WHERE `position` = xposition AND status <> 1;
   ELSE
      INSERT INTO registros (name,position,price) VALUES ( xname, xposition, xprice);
   END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Estou partindo do princípio que sua chave que dispara o ON DUPLICATE KEY seja o `position`, se não for, basta adequar no `SELECT`.

Lembre-se de atualizar os tipos dos campos, pus só como exemplo.

Comment: O position não é minha chave primária, pode me dizer como ficaria esse SELECT?

Comment: position é único e recebe um varchar.Quando eu faço 
SELECT name, position, price FROM registros WHERE status = 0
 INSERT into registros(name,position,price)values('$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]')
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE position = position, name = '$data[1]', position = '$data[2]', price = '$data[3]', qty_try = 0
Recebo o erro: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT into registros

Comment: Vou tentar essa procedure amanhã no trabalho. Obrigado pela ajuda